# Simple javascript rock paper scissors game

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the button , neither the compOutput box or winOutput box show the output that I want them to. I took most of this project from the codecademy example and wanted to try implement it to a webpage. I also want to clear all the fields once the code has run, so could someone give me code for that too? It's just the outputting i'm having a problem with.

```js
var userChoice = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

var computerChoice = Math.random();

 if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
 } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
 } else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
 }


function compare(choice1, choice2) {
 document.getElementById('compOutput').value = computerChoice;
 //tie
 if (choice1 === choice2) {
  document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "The result is a tie!";
 }
 //choice1 rock & choice2 scissors
 else if (choice1 === "rock") {

  if (choice2 === "scissors") {
   document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "rock wins";
  }
 }
 //choice1 paper & choice2 rock
 else if (choice1 === "paper") {

  if (choice2 === "rock") {
   document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "paper wins";
  } else {
   document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "scissors wins";
  }
 }
 //choice1 scissors
 else if (choice1 === "scissors") {

  if (choice2 === "rock") {
   document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "rock wins";
  } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
   document.getElementById('winOutput').value = "scissors wins";
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<body>
 <form>
  <table align="center">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors?</h5>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="userInput"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h5>Computer Choice</h5>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="compOutput"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h5>Winner</h5>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="winOutput"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="generate" value="Click Here" onclick="compare(userChoice, computerhoice)"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>



</body>
```

Comment: I'd suggest just using a listener in Javascript to detect a click of the button and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var winConditions = {
  rock: 'scissors',
  paper: 'rock',
  scissors: 'paper'
}

document.getElementById('generate').onclick = function() {
 var userChoice = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
 var computerChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

 compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
  document.getElementById('compOutput').innerText = choice2;

  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    result = 'The result is a tie!';
  } else if (winConditions[choice1] === choice2) {
   result = 'Player wins!';
  } else {
   result = 'Computer wins';
  }
  
  document.getElementById('winOutput').value = result;
}
```

```html
            <body>
                <form>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors?</h5>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="userInput"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Computer Choice</h5>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="compOutput"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Winner</h5>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="winOutput"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="button" id="generate" value="Click Here"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>



            </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1so0gou8/1/

There you go =)

Answer (score 0):

Your `userChoice` variable is set as soon as the page starts, so it will always be empty. What you would want to do is read the input when you click the button instead.

So I would move everything inside the `compare` function, something like this:

```
function compare () {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var computerInput = Math.random();
  var result;

  if (computerInput < .34) {
    computerInput = 'rock';
  } else if (computerInput > .67) {
    computerInput = 'paper';
  } else {
    computerInput = 'scissors';
  }

  // compare userInput to computerInput here.

}
```

Comment: As an added bonus, you can now click multiple times with different results, so you don't have to reload the page ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of handling the same scenario: use a switch/case statement for the complex option list. As to how to blank the fields after the code has run, simply set the userInput and compOutput value to "" after they've run. Of course, by doing so, you're not actually showing the compOutput, so it doesn't really serve a purpose. Also, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/spsq172p/).

```js
function getUserChoice() {
  var userChoice = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  return userChoice.toLowerCase();
}

function getComputerChoice() {

  var computerChoice = Math.random();

  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }

  return computerChoice;
}

compare = function compare() {
  var choice1 = getUserChoice();
  var choice2 = getComputerChoice();
  document.getElementById("compOutput").value = choice2;  
  var winnerEl = document.getElementById("winOutput");

  switch (true) {
    case (choice1 === choice2):
      winnerEl.value = "It's a tie!";
      break;
    case (choice1 === "rock"):
      switch (choice2) {
        case "paper":
          winnerEl.value = "Paper beats Rock - Computer wins!";
          break;
        case "scissors":
          winnerEl.value = "Rock beat Scissors - User wins!";
          break;
      }
      break; // End choice1 === rock

    case (choice1 === "paper"):
      switch(choice2){
        case "rock":
          winnerEl.value = "Paper beats Rock - User wins!";
          break;
        case "scissors":
          winnerEl.value = "Scissors beat Paper - Computer wins!";
          break;
      }
      break;
    case (choice1 === "scissors"):
      switch(choice2){
        case "rock":
          winnerEl.value = "Rock beats Scissors - Computer wins!";
          break;
        case "paper":
          winnerEl.value = "Scissors beats Paper - User wins!"
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert("Please enter either rock, paper or scissors.");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors?</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="userInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5>Computer Choice</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="compOutput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5>Winner</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="winOutput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="generate" value="Click Here" onclick="compare()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```